# I am learning Excel, can someone tell me what's wrong with this please

Tags: excel

```
=IF(AND(A4=">30",B4=">30"),"Good","Bad")
```

What do I need to do to return if both columns are greater than 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with the formula you have provided. However, there are a few things to consider:

The formula uses the logical operator AND to check if both conditions are true. In order for the formula to return "Good", both conditions must be true. If either condition is false, the formula will return "Bad".

The formula compares the values in cells A4 and B4 to the string ">30". This will not produce the intended result, as the comparison is being made between a cell value and a string rather than between two numbers.

In order to compare the values in cells A4 and B4 to a numerical value, you should use a numerical value rather than a string. For example, you could use `=IF(AND(A4>30,B4>30),"Good","Bad")` to compare the values to the number 30.

If the values in cells A4 and B4 are not numeric, the formula will return an error. You may want to consider using the `ISNUMBER` function to check if the cells contain numeric values before performing the comparison. For example, you could use `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A4),ISNUMBER(B4),A4>30,B4>30),"Good","Bad")` to check if the values are numeric and then compare them to 30.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9 for documentation on the and function. This is a good answer.